# Symfony2 - Doctrine autoescaping of input fields

Tags: symfony, doctrine, escaping

I'm using Symfony2 version 2.0.5 with the bundled Doctrine ORM solution. Since I changed the environment from dev to prod, all my form inputs are escaped, when persisting to database. Now I know this is the correct behaviour for preventing sql injections, but when fetching the data back, the string isn't unescaped. Because I directly save JSON strings to database this is causing me big problems.
Also everytime I update this data the string gets escaped again and again.
My Question is, can I deactivate the escaping for certain fields, should I? Or can I unescape the values when fetched from the DB.
And why is this only happening in prod environment? Is this intended?

Best Regards, David!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably caused by PHP configuration — not by Symfony or Doctrine. In `php.ini`, find all options starting with `magic_quotes_` and set them to  `Off`. Don't forget to restart the server.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I read about magic quotes and checked php.ini, but they're all off. I do believe now, that it's not a symfony or doctrine issue. Is there any other possibility? Maybe a wrong character encoding? We actually moved the application to a different server. But the database configuration is the same.

Comment: I just looked at the post data. And the escaping happens there, which tells me that it must be magic quotes. But they are not activated. Is there another mechanic that does these things, except magic quotes?

Comment: Ok I tested if magic quotes are enabled, and they are. Thanks for the help, elnur. Now I need to find where they are enabled. They are not enabled in php.ini. Is there another possibility?

Comment: They could be enabled in `.htaccess` or an Apache virtual host as well. And are you sure you're checking the right `php.ini`? On some systems there may be several of them: one for `mod_php`, another for `php-fpm` and yet another for `php-cli`.

Comment: We resolved the issue by setting the appropriate php-flag in the local .htaccess file. Thanks again for your help, @elnur.